# Stop playing WAV file when progress reaches 100

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

```pascal
procedure TfrmWelcome.tmr1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  pgb1.StepBy(10);
  imgWelcome.Stretch := True;
  if (pgb1.Position = 10) then
  begin
    sndPlaySound('Mammoth.wav', SND_NODEFAULT or SND_ASYNC); // plays Wav File
  end;
```

How do I stop the WAV file when the progress bar reaches 100?

Comment: You could read the documentation for the function that you call. If you do you will come across the answer to your question. Please do that.

Comment: Please don't take these comments the wrong way. The point is that this information is already out there well indexed, and readily accessible. It will be hugely beneficial to you to learn how to access these resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd798676(v%3Dvs.85)):

> SND_ASYNC
> The sound is played asynchronously and the function returns immediately after beginning the sound. **To terminate an asynchronously played sound, call `sndPlaySound` with `lpszSound` set to `NULL`.**

Try this:

```pascal
procedure TfrmWelcome.tmr1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  pgb1.StepBy(10);
  imgWelcome.Stretch := True;
  Case pgb1.Position of
    10: begin
      sndPlaySound('Mammoth.wav', SND_NODEFAULT or SND_ASYNC); // plays Wav File
    end;
    100: begin
      sndPlaySound(nil, SND_ASYNC); // stops Wav File
    end;
  end;
end;
```